# Using `CGAL::compute_intersection_points` on coplanar segments in 3D

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

Is it possible to use `CGAL::compute_intersection_points` on a bunch of `Segment_3`s which are coplanar? I've browsed https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classArrangementTraits__2.html searching for instances of `ArrangementTraits_2` which might allow this but to no avail.

More generally, can I use the 2D Arrangements package with 3D coplanar segments?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing out of the box. However, I have a module (which I haven't extensively debugged) referred to as a projection traits, which can be used to do the job. I'll try to push it to CGAL. In the meanwhile you can download it from [here](https://github.com/efifogel/cgal/blob/Aos_2-projection_traits-efif/Arrangement_on_surface_2/include/CGAL/Arr_projection_traits_xy_3.h) and an example of use from [here](https://github.com/efifogel/cgal/blob/Aos_2-projection_traits-efif/Surface_sweep_2/examples/Surface_sweep_2/projected_plane_sweep.cpp). Notice that the module contains a projection to the xy-plane. If you also need projections to the yz and zx planes you will need to duplicate the code of the class template `Arr_projection_traits_xy_3` and apply trivial changes.

Comment: Thanks -- I would actually need to project on an arbitrary plane (e.g. defining it with point + normal). I'll check out your module.